# HTML 5 live video streaming from multiple sources

Tags: javascript, video, html5-canvas

I have created a live video feed on a webpage with HTML 5, it works find but i am wondering is it possible to get video from many different sources.
How it works is it uses the built in webcam, grabs the video feed from that and adds it to the HTML of the page. 
Is there any way I can duplicate this but grab video sources from another webcam? (i.e Have multiple live video feeds on the one page)

index.html

```
<!Doctype html>
<head>
<title>LiveStream</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="booth">
<video id="video" width="400" height="300" autoplay controls></video>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" width="300">

<script src="video.js"></script>

</div>


</body>
```

video.js

```
(function(){

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
video = document.getElementById('video'),
vendorUrl = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

navigator.getMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
                 navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                 navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                 navigator.msGetUserMedia; 



navigator.getMedia({
    video: true,
    audio: true
}, function(stream){

    video.src = vendorUrl.createObjectURL(stream);
    video.play();
}, function(error){
//Error occured!
});

})();
```

I have tried the following with MediaDevices.enumerateDevices but it isn't working!

```
    (function(){

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
video = document.getElementById('video'),
vendorUrl = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

navigator.getMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
                 navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                 navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                 navigator.msGetUserMedia ||
                 navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()

.then(function(devices) {
  devices.forEach(function(device) {

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
video = document.getElementById('video'),
vendorUrl = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

   });
}) 



navigator.getMedia({
    video: true,
    audio: true
}, function(stream){

    video.src = vendorUrl.createObjectURL(stream);
    video.play();
}, function(error){
//Error occured!
});

}
)();
```

Comment: make a second call to getUserMedia and select an other device when prompted? You may use the new [`navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/enumerateDevices) method to first check if there is multiple devices with `kind:'videoInput'`before making a second call.

Comment: Please see my edit above, i have tried with MediaDevices.enumerateDevices but i wasn't able to get it to work!

Comment: There a a few misconceptions here: `navigator.getUserMedia()`worked with a callback function you passed as argument. Your `then()` statement is for a promise, which is returned by the new `navigator.media Devices.getUserMedia()`. Then the for each will loop all devices, including audio ones, so your `forEach` function will iterate through those too, while I'm not even sure the device list returned by the `getDevices` method does have such a forEach function. Also, in this `then` you just set variables, nothing is called.

Comment: Finally what I was proposing was just to make a second call and in the prompt choose an other device. There may have been some way in some implementations to choose the device, using video constraints, but I think it's not in the draft specs anymore. You just have a parameter to choose between front and back camera on mobile phones

Comment: I'm not really sure how to go about doing this, i will research some more

Comment: simply duplicate your html markups (video and canvas that you're not using yet btw) and your `navigator.getMedia()` function. just change the callback so in the second function, you've got the second video element's src being set. I didn't add it as an answer because I can't test it but if your still stuck, I'll do tomorrow (in ~9hours)

Comment: Ok, ill give it a go! If you could add it tomorrow it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

**Important Note**
*The code below  has not been tested in real conditions 
I only have one webcam attached to my computer and it may fail on some systems !*

---

You just have to make a second call to the `getUserMedia`, and in the prompt choose an other device.
There may have been some way in some implementations to choose the device, using video constraints, but I think it's not in the  <sub>still in draft</sub> specs anymore.

Here is a way, using a button, which will create a new video element with a new stream each time :

```js
(function() {
  // We declare once what our video elements should look like
  var video = document.createElement('video');
  video.width = 400;
  video.height = 300;
  video.autoplay = true;
  video.controls = true;
  // Where will those be appended in doc
  var container = document.querySelector('.booth'),
    butt = document.querySelector('button'),
    vendorUrl = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

  navigator.getMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
    navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
    navigator.msGetUserMedia;


  function requestCam() {
      navigator.getMedia({
        video: true,
        audio: true
      }, function(stream) {
        // clone our model video
        var videoEl = video.cloneNode(true);
        container.appendChild(videoEl);

        // wait for the stream has been loaded in the video (kind of useless with autoplay = true)
        videoEl.onloadedmetadata = function() {
          this.play();
        };
        videoEl.src = vendorUrl.createObjectURL(stream);
      }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    }
    // attach the function to the button
  butt.addEventListener('click', requestCam, false);
})();
```

```css
button {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="booth">
  <button>Add a new stream</button>
</div>
```

[Fiddle for chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/wmsdhrtb/1) which blocks stack-snippet® `getUserMedia()` requests

To avoid the use of a button, you could chain your call to `requestCam`, but you'll have to call it after the last one was either approved or denied.

One way would be to insert it in the callback of the `getUserMedia()` ; but you may need to add some counter to avoid an infinite chain of calls.

```js
(function() {
  var video = document.createElement('video');
  video.width = 400;
  video.height = 300;
  video.autoplay = true;
  video.controls = true;
  var container = document.querySelector('.booth'),
    vendorUrl = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

  navigator.getMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
    navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
    navigator.msGetUserMedia;

  var maxVideos = 3;
  
  function requestCam(count) {
      // we made it ? stop right now.
      if(count >= maxVideos) return;
    
      navigator.getMedia({
        video: true,
        audio: true
      }, function(stream) {
        
        var videoEl = video.cloneNode(true);
        container.appendChild(videoEl);
        videoEl.onloadedmetadata = function() {this.play();};
        videoEl.src = vendorUrl.createObjectURL(stream);
        // increment our counter
        requestCam(++count);
      }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    }
   // make our first call with count=0
   requestCam(0);
})();
```

```html
<div class="booth">
</div>
```

[Fiddle for chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/wmsdhrtb/)